# how to evaluate &nbsp; in a string?

Tags: javascript, html, space

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('wsk').textContent === "CASE&nbsp;");
console.log(document.getElementById('wsk').textContent === "CASE ");
```

```html
<span id="wsk">CASE&nbsp;</span>
```

Why are the above log both output false? How should I write the value in 3rd and 4th line so it can evaluates to true?

And by the way, on my page if I replace the "$nbsp;" in the span with a real space, it won't get displayed, why?

Comment: `"CASE"+String.fromCharCode(160)`

Comment: _“And by the way, on my page if I replace the "$nbsp;" in the span with a real space, it won't get displayed, why?”_ - because that’s simply how HTML treats regular whitespace at the beginning or end of the element’s content. If you don’t need an actual non-breaking space there - then you should simply give the span a padding-right.

Comment: You could alternatively use `document.getElementById('wsk').innerHTML === "CASE&nbsp;"` which returns true.

Answer (score 10):

A non-breaking space (0xA0) is not a normal space (0x20)

Try comparing the actual character:

```
document.getElementById('wsk').textContent === 'CASE\xA0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('wsk').innerHTML === "CASE&nbsp;");
```

```html
<span id="wsk">CASE&nbsp;</span>
```